# Run a Laravel 4 request as light as possible

Tags: php, laravel-4

Within a Laravel application I have a messenger polling system. With this I'm guessing that every time a user makes a request all dependencies get loaded with every request. Not really a feature I'm very fond of seeing the load it potentially creates.

Is there a way to circumvent most of Laravel requirements to run.

I really only want to insert a message in the database and select a return response and return it as JSON. So I'm not in need of any views, controllers or modules and want to keep those as clean as possible. I actually don't even want to use the PDO and definitely not the query builder.

I'm guessing it saves a lot of server power just to go from the

```
Route::post(... function({}));
```

Can anybody confirm?

Comment: The problem with this question is the `I'm guessing`.... don't guess, verify that this is the case first

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you recommend a way of testing without performing a complete load test? I cannot, which is the problem in this particular case. If it were up to me I would circumvent the entire Laravel framework and cross domain it. But it's not up to me, so unfortunately I have to guess which is why I need confirmation based on experience which I do not posses in this particular case.

Comment: One way to verify is to look at how the autoloader works in Laravel, see how it only loads what's needed when it's needed

Answer (score 4):

Alot of Laravel components are "lazy loaded" - so they only actually load when they are needed.

> Is there a way to circumvent most of Laravel requirements to run. I really only want to insert a message in the database and select a return response and return it as JSON. So I'm not in need of any views, controllers or modules and want to keep those as clean as possible. I actually don't even want to use the PDO and definitely not the query builder.

To me it seems you want to not use most of the Laravel framework. So if I was you - dont use the Laravel framework. Just use the Request component by itself, or even use the underlying Symphony component.

However, as a side point, it seems like you are trying to optimise something where you dont even know you need to optimise it in the first place. Focus on writing good quality, testable, maitainable code.

The other option is a 'light' framework like [Silex](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex)

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The main project is already built in Laravel. The messenger is an extension. Like I mentioned, if it were up to me I would not use Laravel in this instance and use another domain (through CORS) to do the polling. But apparently that is not an option. So I'm stuck with Laravel on this one and thus want to make it as light as possible. That preferably means to not even use the built in functions and thus make my own connections for database and such. Silex seems good fun though, for that +1

Comment: But why use your own connections/function? Why not just use the Laravel ones? I think your over estimating how "big" Laravel is - especially when in essence it will do exactly the same type of code as what you will do if you code it yourself. Unless you are running a truely huge massive server infrastruture, you just wont get any *real* noticeable difference....

Comment: Plus - if the main project is already built in Laravel - then you should continue to leverage Laravel throughout. Re-writing lots of code for a sub-section is crazy - you are adding alot of code maintenance to the project and will cause problems down the track, either for yourself or for another developer who might take over the whole project.

Comment: That is exactly my point. How can I circumvent laravel. Laravel loads all classes by running the spl_autoload_register() function. That is a lot of "required"'s to run on any level if you only want to insert a tweet sized message. Evenmore, polling is not the leanest technology out there. So in regards to loading a page of a website I would totally agree, but not for polling. We are talking about a 1 or 2 second interval connection per user(!). A PHP connection stays open until page is sent back. The shorter that time, the more connections.

Comment: That is why the question is: what is the fastest load a Laravel instance can do and how do you do it. But based on Mark's answer and a little digging I get his point now. It requires all, no matter what you use. But it doesn't load until you request one of it's functions. So I'm satisfied with that answer, which is: There is no faster way, just request less Laravel functionality and it will be faster (or at least that is what I got from it)

Comment: Precisely. The autoloader will only load the classes that your code actually needs and only as you need them, so the loading and memory overhead is kept to a minimum, and is only as large as you actually need to execute the request that it is handling